Solving DE using factorization
We want to find $y$ such that $$(xD^2+(1-x)D-2(1+x))y=e^{-x}(1-6x)$$.
I wanted to factor out $F(D)$ by assuming $F(D)=(xD-f(x))(D-g(x)$ and then got the two equations $xg+f=x-1$ and $-xg'+fg=-2-2x$ by comparing coefficients but no luck. Finding with inspection doesn't seem to work here. It will be very helpful if someone sheds light on this.

Not tried: maybe $(x^\alpha D - f)(x^{1-\alpha}D - g)$?  You don't know "all the $x$" comes from one factor...

$f(x)=-x-1, g(x)=2$.

@Gonçalo Don't spoil :)

Hint: Try $F(D)=(D-f(x))(xD-g(x))$ . I tested.
